# How are QR codes generated in Qt-C++ and how do can I store one as an image to place it in a pdf file generated?

Tags: c++, pdf, qt5, qr-code, libraries

I want to generate a QR code to encrypt data I am entering what's the easiest way for that to be implemented? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation to suggest any classes that can handle this. There seem to be external libraries but I don't know how to include them. So what steps should I take to solve my problem?

Comment: There is no *standard* class or library in C++ to generate QR codes. You'll need to use one of the many available 3rd-party libraries ... and read the documentation for how to include and use whichever you choose to use.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS toolkit has C++ class libraries available for multiple platforms such as Windows, Linux, and Apple that can generate barcodes, including QR codes. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor) The L_BarCodeWrite(https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/barcode/api/l-barcodewrite.html) function writes the barcode to an image. You can then also use the toolkit to insert this image to a PDF.